# Grafana Alerts - Dashboard link with variables

Tags: variables, grafana, alert, dashboard

We have a dashboard where we use variables like this to select resource.

[image: Dashboard with variables]

When creating an Alert, you can specify Dashboard URI.

However, how can I also specify the variables to the correct resource is selected when the dashboard is opened from the link in the alert?

Just using the UID, when the Dashboard link is clicked from the Alert notification, the default dashboard is opened and just looks like this - instead of showing the Dashboard for the resource alerting:

[image: Dashboard resource not specified]

Can we set it up so the actual link has the values for the variables like this:

grafana.azure.com/d/Wh6Si5g4z/azure-container-apps-container-app-view?orgId=1&var-ds=Azure%20Monitor&var-sub=sub-id&var-rg=my-rg-001&var-containerapp=ca-mycontainerapp-test-001&var-ns=microsoft.app%2Fcontainerapps

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Grafana's Notification Templating](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/fundamentals/alert-rules/message-templating/) and define Dashboard url in template like:

```
*[{{ .Status | toUpper }}] {{ .Labels.alertname }}* <https://azure.grafana.net/d/123xyz/smydashboard?var-probe=All&var-agent=All&var-job={{ .Labels.job | urlquery }}|{{ .Labels.job }}>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.

Where would I add this in ? 

How do I access the values of the variables?

Thanks!

Comment: Documentation related to notification templates can be found here: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/fundamentals/alert-rules/message-templating/